# Radio button array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where at some point you can add multiple rows of the same question. Simplified version looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" value=""/>
<input type="radio" name="opted[]" value="Yes" /> Yes 
<input type="radio" name="opted[]" value="No" /> No
```

Above rows are cloned on every "Add friend" button click. This works nicely for a text field, as I get values from all the rows on submit, but radio button doesn't work because it has the same name and clicking on it interferes with other cloned rows.

Any idea how to get around this issue?

Comment: Change `name="opted[]"` to `name="opted[123]"` where `123` is an unique identifier for your question.

Comment: steelaz if you need help implementing what Rob suggested, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `name="opted[]"` with `name="opted[123]"`, where `123` is an unique identifier, so that each set of answets are grouped.

Then, you can access the form elements through either of the following methods:

```
var method1 = document.getElementsByName("opted[123]");
var method2 = document.querySelectorAll("[name='opted[123]']");
//Both vanilla-JavaScript methods return a NodeList, consisting of all
//  elements with name="opted[123]"
```